# Binomial distribution: calculating the probability of a given number of successes with R

Tags: r, binomial-distribution

I'm a bit lost here, could someone please enlighten me?

Let's say we have this simple example:

> A 2005 survey found that 7% of teenagers (ages 13 to 17) suffer from an extreme fear of spiders (arachnophobia). At a summer camp there are 10 teenagers sleeping in each tent. Assume that these 10 teenagers are independent of each other. What is the probability that at least one of them suffers from arachnophobia?

To compute the answer in R we do `sum(dbinom(1:10, 10, 0.07))`, am I right?

But why? I mean, that sounds to me exactly like the cumulative distribution function. And if so, then shouldn't it be `pbinom` in charge of solving this task?

Comment: To be honest, I'd probably have done `1-dbinom(0,10,.07)` myself, since that's how I'd have worked it out by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, this can be solved with the cumulative distribution function.

Summing the individual probabilities results in:

```
sum(dbinom(1:10, 10, 0.07))
# [1] 0.5160177
```

If you use the function `pbinom`, you obtain the same value:

```
pbinom(0, 10, 0.07, lower.tail = FALSE)
# [1] 0.5160177
```

Note that we have to use the argument `lower.tail = FALSE` to obtain the probability for $X > 0$.